# Как настроить столбики в таблице при добавлении?

Tags: mysql

Нужно сохранять:
1) хеш(32) символа(буквы и цифры).
2) ip адресс
3) дату

Как лучше настроить эти столбики?

Comment: Всмысле как настроить?

Comment: Ну какой тип полей указывать? где что проставлять что бы был правильно, что бы потом при запросах и ответах к mysql не было ошибок

Comment: IP-адрес в каком формате планируете хранить? Числовом или строковом? Будете поддерживать только IPv4 или IPv6. Если не сложно дополните вопрос уточнениями.

Comment: @E_p читал, про все типы данных в mysql читал про таблицы но ничего путёвого не нашел решил спросить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте следующие типы данных:

- хеш `VARCHAR(32)`
- ip адрес `VARCHAR(15)` (IPv4 например 192.168.100.100)
- дата `DATE()` (только для даты без времени, формат 0000-00-00)
- дата и время `DATETIME()` (формат 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

Comment: А почему ip не BIGINT? А как вы собираетесь хранить IPv6 ? Зачем отвечать на такие вопросы когда автор не секунды не подумал даже над правильным вопросом?

Comment: Если автор не подумал - это не значит, что не нужно отвечать на вопрос. Мне так понятно, что автор имел ввиду. Про IPv6 я ничего не писал.